# Is boolean type data is in valid JSON

Tags: android, rest, api

I am working on **Magento2**. When I am trying to access core **Rest API** it is sending me in **200 response** code with `true response body`. Is that valid JSON. 
I studied and found that **RFC 7519** says true is valid JSON. but my question is how a simple boolean variable is valid JSON.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ says it is. The why is because of the RFC

Comment: @RC - But as I am studied a JSON object also know with these brackets {}... How could a simple true be valid JSON?

Comment: http://json.org/. `true` is a literal.

Comment: because the creator of JSON said it is

Answer (score 1):

From [json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is anything a valid JSON or not is not quite a correct question. JSON is a notation. As per http://www.json.org/ it can describe different structures 
(not only the objects) including a simple "value" or literal such as `true` or `false` or `"abc"` or `2`.